# How can I create a JSON in R to match this schema?

Tags: r, json, api, csv, tidyverse

I need to create a JSON file that matches the schema at the end of the post in R. I need this to originate from a CSV file that I will generate and it can be crafted to whichever format will make it easiest to achieve the result. The CSV file will be dynamic in nature, in the below example, the only variables that will change per given file are:

1. day
2. cityName - Can be multiple cityName
3. Type - Each cityName can have multiple types
4. price - Each type will have one price
5. order - Each type will have one order

My CSV in it's first iteration is formatted as such and it can have multiple rows:

| day | cityName | Type | price | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-14 | City1 | 1 | 5 | 50 |
| 2019-03-14 | City1 | 2 | 10 | 75 |
| 2019-03-14 | City2 | 1 | 10 | 50 |
| 2019-03-14 | City2 | 2 | 15 | 75 |
| 2019-03-14 | City2 | 3 | 20 | 100 |

```
{
  "day": "2019-03-14",
  "city": [
    {
      "cityName": "city1",
      "FreightA": [
        {
          "Type": 1,
          "FreightSegments": [
            {
              "price": 10,
              "order": 50
            }
          ]
          
          "Type": 2,
          "FreightSegments": [
            {
              "price": 10,
              "order": 75
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      "cityName": "city2",
      "FreightA": [
        {
          "Type": 1,
          "FreightSegments": [
            {
              "price": 10,
              "order": 50
            }
          ]
          
          "Type": 2,
          "FreightSegments": [
            {
              "price": 15,
              "order": 20
            }
            
            "Type": 3,
            "FreightSegments": [
              {
                "price": 20,
                "order": 100
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've gone through relevant JSON posts and a number of trial and errors and am not able to create it. Any guidance/tips/workflow recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Consider having 2-3 rows so that one can tell how this works

Comment: I've added a few rows now, does this help?

Comment: I'd suggest making your example cover 2 dates with at least one city occurring in both dates, and then updating the JSON to match the input. That way we can be sure what gets nested and what doesn't. (If you changed the last row of input to 2019-03-15 and updated the JSON to match the input, I think that would be nice and clear)

Comment: @GregorThomas, - I've added the updates, the date will always be the same for each row every time the file is generated.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens when there is a different date?

Comment: @onyambu It will be a different file with different permutations of variables. Each day, I need to upload this JSON, each file is date specific and will always be the same per file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)

nest(df, FreightSegments = c(price, order)) |>
  nest(FreightA = c(Type, FreightSegments)) |>
  nest(city = c(cityName, FreightA)) |> 
  toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
# [
#   {
#     "day": "2019-03-14",
#     "city": [
#       {
#         "cityName": "City1",
#         "FreightA": [
#           {
#             "Type": 1,
#             "FreightSegments": [
#               {
#                 "price": 5,
#                 "order": 50
#               }
#             ]
#           },
#           {
#             "Type": 2,
#             "FreightSegments": [
#               {
#                 "price": 10,
#                 "order": 75
#               }
#             ]
#           }
#         ]
#       },
#       {
#         "cityName": "City2",
#         "FreightA": [
#           {
#             "Type": 1,
#             "FreightSegments": [
#               {
#                 "price": 10,
#                 "order": 50
#               }
#             ]
#           },
#           {
#             "Type": 2,
#             "FreightSegments": [
#               {
#                 "price": 15,
#                 "order": 75
#               }
#             ]
#           },
#           {
#             "Type": 3,
#             "FreightSegments": [
#               {
#                 "price": 20,
#                 "order": 100
#               }
#             ]
#           }
#         ]
#       }
#     ]
#   }
# ]
```

---

Using this input:

```
df = read.table(text = 'day     cityName    Type    price   order
2019-03-14  City1   1   5   50
2019-03-14  City1   2   10  75
2019-03-14  City2   1   10  50
2019-03-14  City2   2   15  75
2019-03-14  City2   3   20  100', header =T)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply @GregorThomas, how do I remove the "[" at the start and the "]" at the end whilst retaining everything else, is that possible? The schema I'm working with starts with { and ends with }.

Comment: You could write a little function to remove the first and last characters of a string, `remove_first_last = function(x) {substr(x, start = 2, stop = nchar(x) - 1)}` and stick that on the end, `... |> remove_first_last()`.

Comment: thank you for your help. Working with your solution, I'm able to resolve my problem and in turn save myself a tremendous amount of time daily. Appreciate it! :)